# VS2017 template specialization error cannot convert from 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)' to 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)'

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, variadic-templates, template-specialization

This is a simplistic version of a codebase that I am migrating to VS2017.
The following code compiles in VS2013 and Intel C++ compiler 2017 update 4 but not in VS2013.

```
#include  <type_traits>

template<typename F, F f>
struct S1
{};
template<typename F, F f>
struct S2
{};

template<typename F, F f>
using BaseType = typename std::conditional<std::is_member_function_pointer<F>::value, S1<F, f>, S2<F, f>>::type;

template<typename Class, typename... Args>
Class * call_constructor(Args... args)
{
    return new Class(args...);
}

template<class Class, typename... Args>
struct Constructor : BaseType<Class *(*)(Args...), call_constructor<Class, Args...>>
{
    using ReturnType = Class *;
};

int main() {}
```

I am getting an error on the definition of Constructor class:

> main.cpp(20): error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)' to 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)'
>   note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Constructor' being compiled

If I inherit Constructor from directly S1 or S2 the error goes away. So I think the problem is about the std::conditional definitions.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `template<class T>using type=T;`  Then `struct Constructor : BaseType<type<Class*(Args...)>*, static_cast<type<Class*(Args...)>>(call_constructor<Class, Args...>>)` in an attempt to move any errors "up".  I am afraid your code is still trying to determine overload of `call_constructor`, static cast might help.

Comment: @Yakk The error changed :) error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)' to 'Class *(Args...)'

Comment: Add a star in the static cast...

Comment: @Yarr back to the original one :(  'static_cast': cannot convert from 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)' to 'Class *(__cdecl *)(Args...)'

Comment: Now inside the `()` pass `nullptr`.  That'll eliminate the possibility it is `call_constructor` that caused the problem.  Or pass a fixed function that isn't a template with fixed args.  (The goal is to simplify your code further and see if we can generate an even more minimal example)

Comment: Wait, your code never instantiates `Constructor` right?

Comment: @Yakk yes. if I simplify the call_constructor to not use variadic templates the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying numerous attempts of rewriting the code, a colleague of mine came up with the winning version:

```
template<typename F, F f>
struct BaseType_
{
  using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_member_function_pointer<F>::value, S1<F, f>, S2<F, f>>::type;
};

template<typename F, F f>
using BaseType = typename BaseType_<F, f>::type;

template<class Class, typename... Args>
struct Constructor : BaseType_<Class*(*)(Args...), call_constructor<Class, Args...>>::type
{
  using ReturnType = Class *;
};
```

Perhaps this solves the problem by delaying the instantiation of the inheritance
code. We are not sure :)